# Wordpress categories list, description and post count

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I'm looking for a way to list all categories with their descriptions, and also show a number next to each which represents how many posts (published) are in each category.

So the output would be like:

Category Name 1
The description (3)

Category Name 2
The description (16)

Category Name 3
The description (7)

..etc, where the number in brackets is the number of posts in that category.

I've been using this which is close but it just needs the number of posts as mentioned.

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories('exclude=1&title_li=');
foreach ($categories as $cat) {
echo "<h2><a href=\"".$cat->category_nicename."\">".$cat->cat_name."</a></h2>
      <p>".$cat->category_description."</p>";
   }
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get_categories() returns the category count - see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories#Return_values

...so you can insert it with `$cat->category_count` like this:

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories('exclude=1&title_li=');
foreach ($categories as $cat) {
    echo "<h2><a href=\"".$cat->category_nicename."\">".$cat->cat_name."</a></h2>
          <p>".$cat->category_description."(".$cat->category_count.")</p>";
}
?>
```